# Simple Button on Android Lock Screen with PIN

Tags: android

I am new in this forum and checked different threads here but did not found something similar to what I want to do...

Some Apps like MP3-Players or e.g. Spotify-App add some buttons when the lock screen is active (android nativ lock screen with PIN). In this case the displayed Date will dissapear to give more place to these "new" controls.

I have tried this without succes with a simple widget app by including *android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen"* in the appwidget-provider xml information. The app widget is correctly operating on home screen but I see no widget when my screen locks.

So I think this uses other mechanism, may be an activity that hides the date and display controls on the lock screen.

Did anyone try something like this and can give me some tipp?

Thank you in advance!

Notes:

- I dont want to implement a lock screen app, I would like to display a button and text on my lock screen like some common and existent apps do.
- Used Android Version >= 4.2.2

Comment: Investigating a little bit more I found that such apps like Spotify or TuneIn use the existent android mechanism _"Remote Control Client"_. This mechanism can provide data and respond to play/stop/etc... control buttons which are shown on lock screens. As far I understand this is not suitable to implement custom buttons.